# Where to find the TFS build property definitions?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

In my TFS build system, I see many MSBuild properties, such as:

- $(BinDirectory)
- $(ThisDropDirectory)
- ...

These are not the [MSBuild Reserved and Well-Known Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx). How can I find their definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Run with [diag[nostic]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx) verbosity, it'll dump all of them at the begging of the log during evaluation, albeit not the file logger for some reason, just the console one, not sure what TFS one would do.

```
msbuild Foo.csproj /v:diag /t:NonExistingTargetSoItTerminatesAndKeepLogLessNoisy
```